# How can I replace whole xml elements in a word docx in python as if they were strings

Tags: python, xml, symbols, python-docx

My word document contains several symbol font lines that are not being recorded as text.
When I use python-docx to view the underlying xml I can see the lines not being printed look like this:

```
<w:sym w:font="Symbol" w:char="F0B3"/>
```

but python-docx totally ignores w:sym tags. As if they weren't there at all when I'm extracting text. That means I can't just find and replace the symbols with the correct format. I need to be able to replace them before extracting the tables and text from my documents.

How can I turn the above tree elements into this the **w:t** versions like this:

```
<w:t>≥</w:t>
```

I'm totally fine setting up a dictionary for full line replacements. I just can't work out how to do it without breaking the xml file.

Comment: According to https://github.com/mwilliamson/python-mammoth/issues/55#issuecomment-763174948 it should have been fixed

Comment: Thats for docx to html not docx to docx

Comment: Sorry my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by the `python-docx` API. You'll need to edit the XML in another way.

`python-docx` can give you access to the paragraph XML element (`<w:p>`) in the form of an `lxml.etree._Element` object and then you can use that API to manipulate its children. The basic idea would be to insert a new `<w:t>` element wherever you find a `w:sym` element and then remove the `w:sym` element.

The `lxml.etree._Element` API docs are here: https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html. The code might look something like this:

```
p = paragraph._p
for child_element in list(p):
    if child_element.tag != "w:sym":
        continue
    new_t_element = ...
    child_element.addprevious(new_t_element)
    p.remove(child_element)
```

There are still details of this to work out, but hopefully this gives you a direction to pursue. Perhaps you can post your solution here once you've resolved the details.

Comment: Marked this as an answer because it seems like it would kinda work. Ultimately I used Mammouth to put the docx into HTML then parsed the HTML since it automatically converts the symbols to the unicode version. Then I parsed the html version instead of parsing the docx version with BeautifulSoup. Ugly, but works.

Comment: p.remove() is not working

Answer (score 1):

If you out of luck with python-docx this xsl 1.0 is an alternative:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  
  <!-- Identity template : copy all text nodes, elements and attributes -->   
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="w:sym[@w:font='Symbol' and @w:char='F0B3']">
    <w:t>≥</w:t>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```